# Sentence start with auxiliary-verb

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> Only after the journal transaction has been committed in this fashion can the kernel do the real metadata writes at its leisure; **should the system crash in the middle, the information needed to safely finish the job can be found in the journal.** There will be no filesystem corruption caused by a partial metadata update.

This comes from https://lwn.net/Articles/283161 .
What's the usage of **should** in the highlighted sentence?
**should the system crash in the middle,** How should I interpret it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read "*should the system crash in the middle, the information...can be found in the journal*" as a conditional that would more commonly be expressed as:

> **If** the system **should** crash in the middle, the information...can be found in the journal,

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p237) says this about conditionals with *should*:

> We can suggest that something is unlikely, or not particularly probable, by using *should* in the if-clause.

In a later section called **leaving out if: formal inversion structures** (p238), Swan states:

> In formal and literary styles, *if* can be dropped and an auxiliary verb put before the subject. This happens mostly with *were*, *had* and *should*.

He gives this example:

> Should you change your mind... (=If you should change your mind...)